# Battery at 100% then drops off suddenly to 40%

Tags: lumia, battery, nokia-lumia-620

I am using the Nokia Lumia 620 for about 1 month. Although in general I like the phone, there are some things about it that are rather curious. One is that the usage of the battery follows a strange path. First it will continue 100% for a long time (dependent of the usage sometimes over half a day) and when it has reached the 40% then, even if you don't use the phone, it goes quickly to zero.

On my former phone, a Nokia 701, the path of the usage was quite normal.

Does anybody how to resolve the problem? It happens with all of the apps concerning battery usage, I suppose they all get the data from the OS.

Comment: It could be an issue with the battery, especially as a new phone should discharge in a linear fashion. You could try turning on Battery Saver mode and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @NeilTurner The charge state I think is determined by measuring the voltage output, and those voltages are generally not linearly dependent on the charge state.

Comment: @akid assuming you're not playing video or web browsing while playing music, I see no reason why a new phone's battery % level should jump like that.

Comment: @NeilTurner It's not necessarily jumping, as there doesn't seem to be a discontinuity. OP described the charge to change slow (staying close to 100%), then "normal" (down to 40%) and finally fast. This could perhaps (speculation!) be explained by a charge/voltage curve at the "fully charged" end the voltage hardly drops when the battery is used while at the depleted end the voltage sharply drops while the phone is used. This curve would be specific to every battery, so the correction the operating system can apply when relating voltage and charge is limited. Do you get my point?

Comment: @akid the % indicator doesn't represent the voltage  directly, it indicates the remaining power based on a normal discharge pattern - the point being, the % (the system indicator, not a 3rd party app) *should not* jump down like that with a new phone.

Comment: It makes sense for the phone to hover near 100% for an extended period. The OS fudges the numbers at the high end in order for it to appear "normal". However the drop off at the low end is nit normal, unless you are using the phone more at that time (or an app is). Have you used any battery tracking apps to get more data? You may want to try one like http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=78ce556e-605d-453f-bc34-e4ed49cf2ae5

Comment: @NeilTurner Of course not - as I mentioned earlier, the OS will apply a correction function to compute a charge% out of the measured voltage that is as linear as possible (it would surprise me if any phone had a perfectly linear charge decay). In the case here, the OS correction function might not be perfectly suited for the battery in question. Anyway, I'm speculating, so I'll stop abusing the comment thread after this post :)

Comment: I thank @NeilTurner and akid for the interesting discussion. I will try the battery tracking app for a while.

Comment: As promised I've used a battery tracking app for a few weeks.

Comment: The results are in line with my former observations, i.e. showing a long time 100% and when reaching the 40%, a sharply drop. When you have loaded the battery till 100% and then disconnect it right away, it doesn't stay long at 100%, but when you don't disconnect it (i.e. when loading at night) then the 100% will remain a long time after disconnecting. So it seems that the 100% isn't 100% at all, but less. For the drop at 40% I don't have an explanation rather then that the 40% must be much less in reality.

Comment: By updating to Windows Phone 8.1 you'll gain better battery performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows Phone 8.1 installed on your phone, you can check what's going on by using the [Battery Saver](http://www.wpcentral.com/microsoft-updates-windows-phone-81-battery-saver-feature-app) App.

It shows you which App are draining the most the battery and from the settings tab you can check the estimate battery life remaining, not only in percentage but also in time.

[image]

As other people in the comments have pointed out please note that the battery consumption is **not** linear, even in the case of an hypothetic uniform use (the only realistic scenario of uniform use is to do not use the phone at all)